# Override Prerequisite in HapiJS Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to write test for a route that makes an external API call in the prerequisite. In the test I'm writing I don't want that call to be made but I want to make use of a stub to simulate the call.

How do I override the prerequisite from my test?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Shot](https://github.com/hapijs/shot)? I haven't either, but it injects a fake HTTP request/response into a node HTTP server for simulating server logic, writing tests, or debugging.

Before your tests run, you could mock the requests you expect to be made, and specify the expected result.

```
const Http = require('http');
const Shot = require('shot');

(function () {

   const dispatch = function (req, res) {
       const reply = 'Hello World';
       res.writeHead(200, { 
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
            'Content-Length': reply.length 
       });
       res.end(reply);
   };

   const server = Http.createServer(dispatch);

   Shot.inject(dispatch, { method: 'get', url: '/api/hello' }, (res) => {
       console.log(res.payload);
   });
})()
```

Comment: Thanks @mykeels. Actually I just came across the shot package some minutes ago. I'm going through it's documentation though not too explanatory but I'm looking to make use of it to mock external API calls.